# MATLAB: Mapping Values to Index of Other Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Can any MATLAB experts help out with this:

I have the following two arrays:

```
A = [1 1 3 4 4 4 4 4];
B = [6 7 8 9];
```

I would like to make a third array that uses the values of "A" as sort of pointers to the array in B.  So, the final result would be:

```
C = [6 6 8 9 9 9 9 9];
```

Every element of "A" is mapped to an index in "B".

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Sorry, forgot to mention: I'm looking for a non-loop solution.  This would work (I think), but it uses looping:

```
C = [];
for i = 1:length(A)
   C = [C B(A(i))];
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `B(A)`. It treats the elements of `A` as indices into `B` and returns the an array with the same size as `A`.

Comment: Awesome. Worked perfectly - thanks! I'll accept after the min. time has expired.